# Kendo Barchart custom tooltip

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-tooltip

Is it possible to use a custom tooltip text from datasource?

i have a datasource schema like this:

```
           schema: {
                data: "d",
                model: {
                    fields: {
                        text: { type: "string" },
                        value: { type: "number" },
                        desc: { type: "string " }
                    }
                }
            }
```

and I want to use text for base bar values, and desc for tooltip so I have this configuration:

```
            series: [{
                field: "value",
                categoryField: "desc"
            }],
            categoryAxis: [{
                field: "text"
            }]
```

and in the tooltip configuration:

```
            tooltip: {
                visible: true,
                template: "#= category # : #= value # minutes"
            }
```

this configuration does not seem to work. Is there any way I can use `desc` field only for tooltip?

Comment: the reason behind this is that i need to show ID's for axis values (because long descriptions with rotation dont work very well on kendo barchart) and use desc text to show on tooltip the description from that ID.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use dataItem object in kendo template:

```
tooltip: {
    visible: true,
    template: "#= dataItem.desc # minutes"
}
```

Here is dojo example: http://dojo.telerik.com/IYOZO.